# my web pages are not opening until I turn vs code live server how can i fix it?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I really want someone to help me I have a serious issue with vs code live server everything is perfectly working but once I completed my project I can't open my web pages without turning the live server on, whenever I want to check my web pages I have to open it in the vs code then turn on the live server is there a way I can fix it I want to open web page directly rather first open it in vs code than turn on the live server...

Comment: what is the project stack you are working on ? React ?

Comment: When a file is open in vs code, you can't change if from other programs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your folder where you have saved html file and then double click the html file so it will be be opened as a html document in your browser

Comment: thank you sooooo much it's working now as you guid me

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific. What do you mean by "opening directly"? Do you mean double clicking the html-file? What are you coding? Only html/css or js with libraries?

What happens if you double click the html file?

**Browser opens the html:**

Does it open the browser and shows a page without styling? If you don't see your css applied you might have added a prepending slash to your css link. Change your css link to something similar as this (the path should point to your css file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Note: their is no prepending slash in the href attribute value. A prepending slash will work in a live server environment but will fail when the browser reads the file locally (= double clicking).

**Browser does not open html:**

If your browser does not open when double clicking the html file your browser is not configured as the program to launch html files. You could instead drag your html file into an open browser window. And look on the internet how to change your settings to launch your favorite browser when double clicking html files.